# SQL how to count total rows for each customer with group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with a question that said "which city of customers watches the most number of movies? (based on the number of films rented)".

I am doing this using the Seikila sample database in MySQL. The city entity has no relationship with rental and customer entity, but there's a address entity contain address_id which is id-dependent to customer entity. Then, the address entity has an attribute called city_id which the city entity also have got. And the customer_id attribute linked both customer and rental entities.

Also, I have to calculate the total number of films each customer in each city have rented.

I have only done the join part (code updated):

```
select rental_id,cust.customer_id,city.city_id,city.city from rental as r  
inner join customer as cust on r.customer_id=cust.customer_id inner join
address as a on cust.address_id=a.address_id inner join city as city on
city.city_id=a.city_id
```

I realized that I should add city_id to the table, so my question will be:

how to count the number of rows of an unique customer_id so that I can get **the total numbers of film rented** of **in each city**, and with a group by?

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`. You even wrote that in the question title.

Comment: I know it's using count() but I want to count separately each customer_id,not the total numbers of customers

Comment: It sounds like you just want the count of rentals by city, not the count of customers.

Comment: Hum...the question says "Which city (of customers) watches the most number of movies (based on the number of films)"  so yeah...I misunderstood the question a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)` to get the total number of movie rentals, and group it by city.

```
SELECT city.city, COUNT(*) AS total_rentals
FROM rental AS r
INNER JOIN customer AS cust on r.customer_id = cust.customer_id
INNER JOIN address AS a on cust.address_id = a.address_id
INNER JOIN city ON city.city_id = a.city_id
GROUP BY city.city_id
ORDER BY total_rentals DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you also want to know the number of customers in that city, you can add `COUNT(DISTINCT cust.customer_id)` to the `SELECT` list.